# How to call a user-defined syscall as a function

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls, openbsd

Lets say I have a user-defined syscall: foo (with code number 500).

To call it, I simply write in a C file:

```
syscall(SYS_code, args);
```

How can I call it using just `foo(args)`?

Comment: "How can I call it using just foo(args)?" - Create a function `foo`, which performs required system call. So other code could simply call `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Not unless you first convince the kernel developers that your syscall is worth being added, then it gets added, and then userspace libraries such as the standard C library (glibc on most Linux distributions) decide to implement a wrapper for it like they do for most of the syscalls.

In other words: since the above is impossible, all you can do is define the wrapper function yourself in your own program.

```c
#define SYS_foo 500

long foo(int a, char *b) {
    return syscall(SYS_foo, a, b);
}
```